# How to reference an element that is altered by knockout component?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, requirejs, dropzone.js

I'm trying to build a reusable Knockout.js `upload` component that consists of a Dropzone.js instantiation on a form element.

AMDified Knockout `Upload` component:

```
define(['knockout', 'dropzone', 'jquery', 'text!components/upload/upload.html'], function(ko, Dropzone, $, htmlString) {
    function UploadViewModel(params) {
        var self = this;

        self.dropzoneId = ko.observable(params.dropzoneId);
        self.postLocation = ko.observable(params.postLocation);

        Dropzone.options.uploadedFilesDropzone = {
            // Dropzone options here
        };
    }

    var myDropzone = new Dropzone('#' +  self.dropzoneId(), { url: self.postLocation() });

    return { viewModel: UploadViewModel, template: htmlString };
});
```

Template being used:

```
<form method="post" class="dropzone" enctype="multipart/form-data"  data-bind="attr: { action: postLocation, id : dropzoneId }">
</form>
<button id="upload">Upload</button>
```

And when I create it in a page:

```
<upload params="dropzoneId: 'uploadFilesDropzone', postLocation: 'missioncontrol/create/upload'"></upload>
```

Page require.js script:

```
    require(['common'], function() {
        require(['knockout'], function(ko) {

            ko.components.register('upload', {require: 'components/upload/upload'});
        });
    });
```

As you can see, when I create my `upload` component in the DOM, I am passing through an ID and an action HTML attribute so I can customize the naming of each of these upload components (since they're supposed to be reusable, right?).

However, I'm running into a problem in my `Upload` component script when I create a new `Dropzone`:

```
    var myDropzone = new Dropzone('#' +  self.dropzoneId(), { url: self.postLocation() });
```

The problem is, despite passing through as `params` the name I want the ID attribute to take on, at the time this function is called, the knockout bindings on the main page have not occurred yet, so no matter what I do, any element ID I pass through will be not defined and give me this error:

```
Error: Invalid dropzone element.
```

Because an element with an ID of `self.dropzoneId()` does not exist yet, as the bindings haven't been applied.

What can I do to work around this?

Comment: Create a custom binding for the Dropzone and create it in the init?

Comment: What about setting a default? dropzoneId is an observable, so you could do `'#' + (self.dropzoneId() || 'default-zone')`. If you have multiple dropzones like this, just add a counter in the constructor and append it to the ID. As soon as the dropzone is loaded, modify the ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since my comment suggestion worked, I'll just write it up as an answer.

As a rule, any DOM manipulation in Knockout should be done in a binding. Any widgets that need to be attached to DOM elements should have custom bindingHandlers created for them. The widget can be created in the `init` section.

Comment: Indeed, this is what Steve Sanderson (Knockout.js creator) recommends. Thanks Roy.